# unable to create image using simplecursoradapter

Tags: android

im easily able to use for textviews but textview with imageview like contacts name,number and image display sort of listing i m suffering with i have searched many blogs but without success please help....

```
public class Listmain extends ListActivity
{ 
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        try 
        { 
            Data_baseActivity db=new Data_baseActivity(this); 
            db.open(); 
            InputStream is; 
            Cursor cursor =db.getAllContacts1(); 
            int len=cursor.getCount(); 
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, cursor, new String[] { "image", "name"}, new int[] { R.id.icon, R.id.label}); 
            adapter.setViewBinder(new ProductViewBinder()); 
            setListAdapter(adapter); 
            db.close(); 
         } 
         catch(Exception e) 
         { 
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString()+" error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         }
    }
}



public class ProductViewBinder implements ViewBinder 
{
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            if (view instanceof ImageView) 
            {
                byte[] result = cursor.getBlob(3);//my image is stored as blob in db at 3
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
                ImageView im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
                im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
               return true;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Listmain.this, e.toString()+" err", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
cr.getBlob(cr.getColumnIndex("Image")) //where "Image" is column name.
```

I used this and it worked.

If it doesn't worked. Please post the `toast message` that u r getting in the `exception`

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a class and extend `simpleCusorAdapter` in it.
2. Create a constructor in the class and take parameters: `context, layout, cursor, from, to`
3. In the constructor, intialize the views of your customized layout like `this.imageContainer=container`.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.service;

import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Listmain extends ListActivity{
    Bitmap bmaps;
    private FriendAdapter friendAdapter;
    String forDeletion[][]=null;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         this.setContentView(R.layout.viewer);
         EditText etxData=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
         etxData.setText(null);
         listContacts();
     }

     @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EditText etxData=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
        etxData.setText(null);
        listContacts();
    }

    public void listContacts()
     {
         Data_baseActivity db=new Data_baseActivity(this);
         try
         {

             Resources res=getResources();
             Drawable d = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.no_photo);
             bmaps = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();

             final ListView lv = getListView();
             final EditText etx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
             final ImageButton imgbtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.refresh);

             db.open();
             Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
             if(cursor.getCount()<1)
             {
                 etx.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
             startManagingCursor(cursor);
             int len=cursor.getCount();
             forDeletion=new String[len][4];
             String[] from = new String[] {};
             int[] to = new int[] {};
             this.friendAdapter = new FriendAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, cursor, from, to);
             lv.setAdapter(friendAdapter);
             etx.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){


                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                }


                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {

                }


                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int s,
                        int e, int h) {
                try
                {
                     Data_baseActivity db1=new Data_baseActivity(Listmain.this);
                     db1.open();
                     Cursor searchCursor =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,
                             ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?" , new String[]{c+"%"}, null);
                     startManagingCursor(searchCursor);
                     String[] from = new String[] {};
                     int[] to = new int[] {};
                     friendAdapter = new FriendAdapter(Listmain.this, R.layout.rowlayout, searchCursor, from, to);
                     lv.setAdapter(friendAdapter);
                     db1.close();
                }
                catch(Exception es)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Listmain.this, es.toString()+" g", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                }

             });


         }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString()+" error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
         db.close();
     }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent intent=new Intent(Listmain.this,Editing.class);
        String send[]=new String[4];
        send[0]=forDeletion[position][0];
        send[1]=forDeletion[position][1];
        send[2]=forDeletion[position][2];
        send[3]=forDeletion[position][3];
        intent.putExtra("com.service.id", send);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    public class FriendAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
     {
         private final Context mContext;
         private final int mLayout;
         private final Cursor mCursor;
         private final int mNameIndex;
         private final int mIdIndex;
         private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
         private int lookUp;
         private final class ViewHolder {
             public TextView name;
             public ImageView image;
            public TextView number;
            public ImageView endis;
         }

         public FriendAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
             super(context, layout, c, from, to);

             this.mContext = context;
             this.mLayout = layout;
             this.mCursor = c;
             this.mNameIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
             this.mIdIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
             this.lookUp=mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY);
             this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
         }

         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             try
             {
             if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                 ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                 String name = mCursor.getString(mNameIndex);
                 if (convertView == null) 
                 {
                         convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayout, null);
                         viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                         viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                         viewHolder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
                         viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                         viewHolder.endis = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.endis);
                         convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                 }

                     String number = null;
                     String image = mCursor.getString(mIdIndex);
                     String lookup=mCursor.getString(lookUp);
                     long lid=Long.parseLong(image);
                     Bitmap bmp = loadContactPhoto(mContext.getContentResolver(),lid,mContext);
                     if(bmp==null)
                     {
                         bmp=bmaps;
                     }
                     viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                     viewHolder.name.setText(name);
                     Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? " , new String[] {image}, null);
                     String num=null;
                     while(cur.moveToNext()) 
                     {
                         num = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                         num=num+"\n";
                     }
                     number=num;
                     viewHolder.endis.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     viewHolder.number.setText(number);
                     forDeletion[position][0]=name;
                     forDeletion[position][1]=number;
                     forDeletion[position][2]=image;
                     forDeletion[position][3]=lookup;
                }
             }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Listmain.this, e.toString()+" 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

             return convertView;
         }

     }

     public  Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long id,Context ctx) {
         InputStream input=null;
        try
        {
         Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
         input= ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Image formation error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bmp;
       }
}
## Heading ##
```